# Swashbuckle is generating an invalid JSON with System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair schema

Tags: swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET core API that is generating invalid JSON and I am not sure where it is coming from. According the swagger validator the problem is the following schema.

```
"attribute components.schemas.Schema name System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String,\
  \ System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String,\
  \ System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]],\
  \ System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]\
  \ doesn't adhere to regular expression ^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+$"
```

Here is a copy of of the actual JSON:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "readOnly": true
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "nullable": true,
            "readOnly": true
          }
        }
      }
```

I have searched through the project to find where this is being referenced and I am not finding anything. I also have seen System classes in the schema previously. Does anyone know why this would appear in the swagger docs?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue while doing a Upgrade from .NET Framework to .NET6.
I tracked down where this reference came from and found that i still had a Endpoint with Returntype `HttpResponseMessage` instead of `IActionResult`